# No Wireless Network On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

Its annoying. 2 months ago I installed ubuntu replacing windows 10, the reason is that I lost my wireless network functionality on windows 10. I tried almost every possible tricks, but no luck. Then I switched to ubuntu, it was running well for the first 3 - 4 days, but suddenly the same issue appeared. Wifi suddenly turns itself off, after a reboot it may work or may not. What should I do now?

When I tried to get my wireless info script, I found something below:

```
##### iwconfig ##########################

wwp0s29u1u2i1  no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

ppp0      no wireless extensions.
```

Is this related to my no wireless issue?

The result of:

```
sudo lshw -C NetWork | grep -i wireless
```

[image: terminal showing no output for the command as one would expect given it's the wrong command]

The wireless information for my hardware:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Oct 2017 12:16 IST +0530

Booted last: 15 Oct 2017 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1043:13c7]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5710 IMC Networks UVC VGA Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
ath3k                  20480  0
bluetooth             557056  34 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,ath3k,btusb
wmi                    16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:79584 (79.5 KB)  TX bytes:79584 (79.5 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.202.169.93  P-t-P:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4605 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:4082105 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:520576 (520.5 KB)

wwp0s29u1u2i1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wwp0s29u1u2i1' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

wwp0s29u1u2i1  no wireless extensions.

ppp0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     700    0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ppp0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       837     1  0 12:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ttyUSB2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           gsm
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceModem
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         HUAWEI Technology
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        HUAWEI Mobile
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         option1, cdc_ether
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       ppp0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Vodafone Vodafone Live
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       493825f8-fb82-43e4-abe0-236fe9e34b79
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   493825f8-fb82-43e4-abe0-236fe9e34b79 | Vodafone Vodafone Live
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.202.169.93/32
IP4.GATEWAY:                            0.0.0.0
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.172.30.244
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.172.30.245

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         atl1c
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.0.1.1-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         huawei_0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           gsm
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceModem
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ofono
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /huawei_0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Hotspot
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hotspot | type=wifi | permissions=user:subhamchbt:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Hotspot
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

wwp0s29u1u2i1  no frequency information.

ppp0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

enp4s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

wwp0s29u1u2i1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

ppp0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     36C0F7AEF3B569F1798216D
depends:        bluetooth
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload 

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf]
options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   13.742709] cdc_ether 2-1.2:1.1 wwan0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, Mobile Broadband Network Device, <MAC 'wwp0s29u1u2i1' [IF2]>
[   14.212970] cdc_ether 2-1.2:1.1 wwp0s29u1u2i1: renamed from wwan0
[   20.099786] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: I would use an ethernet cable and see if the problem is only the wifi

Comment: yes, i am using huawei data card after that problem

Comment: Please run `sudo lshw -C NetWork | grep -i wireless` and paste into your question!

Comment: @Zanna I have edited my question, and added wireless-info.txt

Comment: it looks like the wireless network card is not detected at all. Maybe it has come loose?

Comment: If the wireless network adapter didn't work in Windows what makes you think it will work in Ubuntu? This appears to be unrelated to Ubuntu (or Windows for that matter) but a hardware issue. See @Zanna's comment.

Comment: @Zanna The weird thing is that the bluetooth on the same card is detected. Maybe it is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: @SubhamChakraborty Check BIOS settings.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I didn't switched to ubuntu only because of wifi adapter. I don't know why you think you are genius without having such general knowledge.

Comment: @Zanna I checked my BIOS and its okay there.